# Elastic search - trying to trigger search api in recursive way

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In elastic search i do want to do a recursive kind of search. Like based on first query result, i have to fire the next query ( first query result is the input of second query). It should keep on query till the result comes as `null`.

For example:

From the below table data.

if am searching for the value `car`, it should give the `id` and `value` and should check for the `parent_id`. Then, `parent_id` is the input and it should check for `id` and `value` again.

Likewise, it should go till `parent_id` is `null`.

```
id      Parent_id       Value
1       null            null
2       45              Hundai
3       89              Volvo
4       1               Benz
5       3               Audi
6       4               BMW
7       6               car
```

If i search for a Value `car` i should get the following details.

```
id      Value
7       car
6       BMW
4       Benz
1       null
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is actually `SELF JOIN` operation.

You can refer to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/parent-join.html#_multiple_levels_of_parent_join) as how you can model your data via multiple levels of parents but keep in mind that it comes at a very high querying cost. And again, the documents in `elasticsearch` shouldn't be modeled the way we model the data in `RDBMS`.

What you can do is to have your documents modeled in `denormalized` way, and store that information as separate field.

For e.g. you can have a field called as `hierarchy` as mentioned in the below document which is to be created during `indexing` operation and use simple querying to fetch the results you are looking for.

```
POST tempindex/1
{
  "id": 7,
  "name": "Car",
  "parentid": 6,
  "hierarchy": "7/6/5/2/1/null"
}
```

And then you can simply have the below query work for you which would return you the list of documents which ends with `null`

```
GET tempindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "hierarchy": "null"
    }
  }
}
```