# Parent/User Relationship using Join type Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, join, types, parent-child, hierarchy

I have list of users and there is one field called parent, some users might not have parents.

I want to get the full parent hierarchy, full child hierarchy for given user id.

What should by my mapping on that?

Here is the example.

**UserId, Name, ParentId**

1 .          , KP .    ,  NULL/Blank/0

2 .      ,  RT .    ,  1

3 .     ,  TH .     , 2

4 .     ,  MS      , 3

If I want to get all child hierarchy of UserId-2 that should be Ids (3,4,....) and i also want to get the Parent hierarchy of 4 that should be (3,2,1...!).

Is it possible to achieve this in ES6.3? If yes, what should be my Mapping? I might have Single/Multiple Parents.

Comment: Yes this is possible. Refer to this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/parent-join.html

Otherwise I'd suggest you to denormalize your data as I've mentioned in this answer Let me know it it helps! https://stackoverflow.com/a/52556121/3838328

Comment: In particular check this section https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/parent-join.html#_multiple_levels_of_parent_join

Comment: I have tried join.. here is my mapping.. {"mappings": {
      "user": {
        "properties": {
          "user_type": {
            "type": "join",
            "eager_global_ordinals": true,
            "relations": {
              "parent": "child"
            }
          }}}}
  
}

Comment: If i want to get all deep children/ parents how can i do that?